# Does a Muslim wife have to cook and clean for her husband?

Tags: women, husband-wife

[In response to this question](https://seekersguidance.org/answers/marriage-and-divorce/do-i-have-to-cook-and-clean-for-my-husband-if-i-work-too/), Ustadha Shazia Ahmad quotes a Shafi'i jurist,

> “45.1 (Abu Ishaq Shirazi:) A woman is not obliged to serve her husband
> by baking, grinding flour, cooking, washing, or any other kind of
> service, because the marriage contract entails, for her part, only
> that she let him enjoy her sexually, and she is not obligated to do
> other than that. Rather, it is considered sunna in our school for
> the wife to do the housework...[al-Muhadhdhab fi Fiqh al-Imam
> al-Shafi’i]

However, U. Shazia Ahmad still goes on to say,

> A woman is not obliged to work, but rather, she is expected to take
> care of her husband, children, and home. This is from the sunnah in
> our school, and it is considered obligatory in the Hanafi school. In
> traditional societies, a woman is honored and admired for her
> efficiency, cooking skills, and cleanliness in the home. You will find
> that these womanly duties, when done well, contribute to the safety,
> security, love, and emotional stability of a Muslim household. Do not
> undermine them for they are important things that affect the whole
> family.

She also ends her answer with a link to another Q&A about the obligation of [obeying husband in everything](https://seekersguidance.org/answers/general-counsel/do-i-have-to-obey-my-husband-in-everything/).

So, this leaves me confused:

According to Islam (the Shafi'i school, in particular) is it a woman's duty to cook and clean?

If cooking and cleaning are not a woman's duty by default, would they become her duties if her husband requires her to do them? (given that obeying husband regarding permissible actions is obligatory)

Comment: She is consistent in saying it is Sunnah rather than an obligation. I am not sure where the confusion is.

Comment: would it become an obligation if the husband requires it?

Comment: @HK70 The Hadith of Fatima (ra) complaining to the Prophet (pbuh) of the harsh nature of her work and the Prophet's reaction shows Islam has a sense of gender roles, check this video for explanation,  https://youtu.be/kgqrhPUhINc